# Extracting Download Attachments of a specific folder from Outlook Mailboxes using C#. I want this to be run from server where is no Outlook Installed

Tags: c#, outlook

I wanted a solution of downloading the attachment of the latest mail from a specific folder in Outlook and save it to a specific location.

Note- This will be run at server where is no Outlook installed.

Answer (score 0):

Then (assuming you want to connect to an Exchange mailbox), you will have to use [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd877045(v%3Dexchg.140)) or it [.Net wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications).